Update wordpress user role using external API credentials
I am new to the platform officially but have used it for many years solving many of my problems, I hope you can help me now.
I'm integrating a network provider's API with wordpress, woocmmerce and woocommerce subscriptions. Essentially I need to check the subscription status on the external API, retrieve the current state (Grace/Active) and then update the user role from subscriber to customer if its any of the two, or downgrade to default subscriber role if else. I'm using ultimate member for user role management and sign up forms. The problem I'm having is that when i activate my plugin, it crashes the site with a fatal error whenever the msisdn is referenced. I'm trying to establish what I'm doing wrong. I'm also struggling to get data back from the API in postman but I believe thats a server credentials issue which i'm liasin with the service providers tech guy to troubleshoot.
This is the full code. I've removed sensitive data for safety.
<?php

// AWS Signature Version 4 Helper Function
function get_aws_signature_v4($access_key, $secret_key, $region, $service, $request_method, $request_uri, $query_string, $payload, $timestamp) {
    $date = gmdate('Ymd', $timestamp);
    $date_time = gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z', $timestamp);
    $scope = "$date/$region/$service/aws4_request";
    $canonical_uri = $request_uri;
    $canonical_querystring = $query_string;
    $canonical_headers = "host:############\nx-amz-date:$date_time\n";
    $signed_headers = "host;x-amz-date";
    $hashed_payload = hash('sha256', $payload);

    $canonical_request = "$request_method\n$canonical_uri\n$canonical_querystring\n$canonical_headers\n$signed_headers\n$hashed_payload";
    $string_to_sign = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n$date_time\n$scope\n" . hash('sha256', $canonical_request);

    $signing_key = hash_hmac('sha256', 'aws4_request', hash_hmac('sha256', $service, hash_hmac('sha256', $region, hash_hmac('sha256', $date, 'AWS4' . $secret_key, true), true), true), true);
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $string_to_sign, $signing_key);

    return "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=$access_key/$scope, SignedHeaders=$signed_headers, Signature=$signature";
}

// Function to get the subscription status
function get_subscription_status($msisdn) {
    $access_key = '###########';
    $secret_key = '################';
    $region = 'eu-west-1';
    $service = 'execute-api';
    $request_method = 'GET';
    $request_uri = '/subscription/{subscription_id}';
    $timestamp = time();
    $payload = '';

    // Retrieve partner ID dynamically (replace with actual partner ID retrieval logic)
    $partner_id = ##;

    // Request partner details to get subscriptions
    $auth_header = get_aws_signature_v4($access_key, $secret_key, $region, $service, $request_method, "/partner/{$partner_id}", "", $payload, $timestamp);

    $headers = [
        'Accept: application/vnd.sdp+json;version=1.4',
        'X-Amz-Date: ' . gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z', $timestamp),
        'Authorization: ' . $auth_header,
        'x-api-key: ############'
    ];

    $response = wp_remote_get('############' . $partner_id, [
        'headers' => $headers
    ]);

    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        return 'Error: ' . $response->get_error_message();
    }

    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    $subscription_data = json_decode($body, true);

    // Find subscription matching user's MSISDN
    $user_subscription = null;
    foreach ($subscription_data as $subscription) {
        if ($subscription['user_msisdn'] === $msisdn) {
            $user_subscription = $subscription;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$user_subscription) {
        return 'Subscription not found for MSISDN: ' . $msisdn;
    }

    // Get subscription status
    $subscription_id = $user_subscription['subscription_id'];
    $request_uri = "/subscription/{$subscription_id}";
    $auth_header = get_aws_signature_v4($access_key, $secret_key, $region, $service, $request_method, $request_uri, "", $payload, $timestamp);

    $response = wp_remote_get('##########' . $request_uri, [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept: application/vnd.sdp+json;version=1.4',
            'X-Amz-Date: ' . gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z', $timestamp),
            'Authorization: ' . $auth_header,
            'x-api-key: ###########'
        ]
    ]);

    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        return 'Error: ' . $response->get_error_message();
    }

    $status_data = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);

    // Determine user role based on subscription status
    $role_to_set = 'subscriber'; // Default role for inactive or other statuses
    if ($status_data['status_name'] === 'GRACE' || $status_data['status_name'] === 'ACTIVE') {
        $role_to_set = 'customer'; // Set to 'customer' for active and grace statuses
    }

    return $role_to_set;
}

// Function to check and update user role based on subscription status
function check_and_update_user_role($user_id) {
    $user = get_userdata($user_id);
    if (!$user) {
        return;
    }

    $msisdn = get_user_meta($user_id, 'mobile_number', true);
    if (empty($msisdn)) {
        return;
    }

    $new_role = get_subscription_status($msisdn);
    if (!$new_role) {
        return; // Handle error or not found
    }

    $user->set_role($new_role);
}

// Hook into user login, registration, and page load
function trigger_subscription_check($user_id) {
    check_and_update_user_role($user_id);
}

add_action('wp_login', 'trigger_subscription_check');
add_action('user_register', 'trigger_subscription_check');
add_action('wp', function() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        trigger_subscription_check(get_current_user_id());
    }
});

// Shortcode function to display subscription status
function display_subscription_status($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'msisdn' => '',
        ),
        $atts,
        'subscription_status'
    );

    if (empty($atts['msisdn'])) {
        return 'MSISDN is required.';
    }

    $status = get_subscription_status($atts['msisdn']);

    return '<pre>' . esc_html($status) . '</pre>';
}

// Register shortcode
add_shortcode('subscription_status', 'display_subscription_status');

?>
 



I've trippled checked that the msisdn references the number stored under the "mobile_number" meta tag, which I believe it does, as the error log tracks any changes I make to the user's number. I've gone through multiple iterations of the code, attempting to change the user's subscription status in woocommerce subscriptions instead of the user role and that failed dismally, I'm at my wits end as to why its crashing my site, even if i'm not eccessing the API and retrieiving valid data as yet.
Please help.
